# Force ErrorActionPreference when running PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

We use PowerShell for some of our automated build scripts. Unfortunately, by default, PowerShell continues after an error.

Ordinarily, I can change this behaviour by setting `$ErrorActionPreference = Stop`.

I can't see a corresponding command line switch for `PowerShell.exe`, and we (deliberately) run the commands with `-noprofile`, so I can't put it in there.

How do I do this for a build script?

Answer (score 2):

Put it at the top of the script you're running?

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
```

Alternatively, you can also get similar control at the cmdlet level using the ErrorAction parameter.

Comment: That means editing every single script. I'd prefer to find a global solution.

Comment: Have you checked @Marcus' solution? I can offer a solution but it would affect all users.

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be a way to set:

```
powershell -erroractionpreference stop ...
```

The following would work:

```
powershell -command { $ErrorActionPreference = "stop"; .\test.ps1 } -noprofile
```

There is of course nothing to stop the script (re)setting ErrorActionPreference.